# How to get rid of DeprecationWarning in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have downloaded airflow and every time I run a command from the CLI I get this warning:

`/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py:971 DeprecationWarning: The namespace option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the namespace option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.`

How can I remove it?

I assume there is a setting to change in the airflow.cfg file, but don't know which one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kindly provide the Airflow version, and the providers version, like cncf-kubernetes.

Also provide the DAG code snippet.